# Retrieve all media from Firebase storage in 2023

Tags: javascript, firebase-storage

Is there a way to retrieve every img download URL from  firebase storage i tried like this:

```
const mediaRef = ref(storage, 'media'); // Reference to your media folder

    const urls = await Promise.all(mediaRef.items.map(async (item) => {
      const url = await getDownloadURL(item);
      return url;
```

and like this:

```
    const mediaRef = ref(storage, 'media'); // Reference to your media folder
    const result = await storage.listAll(mediaRef);

    const urls = await Promise.all(result.items.map(async (item) => {
      const url = await getDownloadURL(item);
      return url;
```

but noting seems to work.
If there is no such a functionality then what is the workaround?
I saw a question from 6 years ago that there was no functionality for that then its still true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it this way, it worked for me:

```
const FIREBASE_APP = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const FIREBASE_STORAGE = getStorage(FIREBASE_APP);

const listRef = ref(FIREBASE_STORAGE);

listAll(listRef).then(res =>
  res.items.forEach(imageRef =>
    getDownloadURL(imageRef).then(res2 => console.log(res2)),
  ),
);
```